# Fastlane, auto fill package name on upload_to_play_store

Tags: ruby, react-native, cicd, fastlane

Hi I'm new to fastlane and I have a react native iOS & android application which I have setup with fastlane. I have multiple productFlavors for its different app versions:

```
productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        applicationId "com.package.flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        applicationId "com.package.flavor2"
    }
    flavor3 {
        applicationId "com.package.flavor3"
    }
    flavor4 {
        applicationId "com.package.flavor4"
    }
```

Now on my Fastfile, I can generate all the AAB for all flavors using the generic gradle command.

```
gradle( task: 'clean bundle', build_type: 'release', project_dir:'android/')
```

When I try to run the upload command, fastlane asks for package_name paramter

```
upload_to_play_store(release_status: releaseStatus, changes_not_sent_for_review: shouldSendReview)
```

I want to be able to iterate to all flavors and maybe access its applicationId key to append the command with it but Im not sure where to go. Everything I looked into only assumes that project has single package name. Can someone guide me on the ropes for this on fastlane. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke fastlane with the package name. Unfortunately, there are two different ways to do it for different parts of the process.

For `fastlane supply`, you can provide it as a command-line option: `fastlane supply init --package name com.package.flavor1`.

For specific lanes, you have to provide it as an option flag to the lane:

```
lane :flavor1 do |options|
  upload_to_play_store(
    package_name: options[:package_name],
    <etc>
  )
end
```

And then you can invoke the lane with the option: `fastlane flavor1 package_name:com.package.flavor1`